# vue.js how to use props with single file components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am very new to `vue.js` ,

I am using single file components with webpack , I am trying to calculate the sum of `{{operating.totaloperating}}`, I understand that to accomplish this I need to pass `operating` data back to script as prop, am I right? 
How can I do that? When I try to pass it as prop, it says undefined.

I can pass props to this component only from template, but not in the file itself.

```
<template>
    <tr v-for="operating in operatings" :operating="operating">
        <th scope="row">{{$index+1}}</th>
        <td>{{operating.name}}</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>{{operating.totaloperating}}</td>
    </tr>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['operating'],
        data: function () {
            return {
                preloader: true,
                operatings: []
            }
        },

        methods: {

            fetchTotal: function () {
                this.$http.get('/api/totaloperating').then((response) => {
                    this.$set('operatings', response.json()),

                });
            }
        },



        ready: function () {

            this.fetchTotal()

        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What does response contain?

Comment: response contains an array [{"id":1,"totalsalary":"900"},{"id":2,"totalsalary":"100"}] ,  i want to reach total: 1000  .  :operating="operating"    this attribute not working inside of single file component . i returns undefined.

Comment: Then where is `totaloperating`???

Comment: Sorry , i wrote wrong , its not totalsalary , the array is  [{"id":1,"totaloperating":"900"},{"id":2,"totaloperating":"100"}]

Comment: Works to me https://jsfiddle.net/gurghet/dg32j4v0/

Comment: Thanks but this is not an issue , i can display data in template , my problem is , i cant return data to script section again to calculate sum .  <tr v-for="operating in operatings" :operating="operating"> :operating attribute (prop) returns undefined . Maybe my question should be how can i reach data in script tags after i set it? as i said i can list rendering , no problem with that.

Comment: Is http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Prop-Binding-Types what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You should remove `:operating="operating"` from the `tr` since is not a component.
Also the prop `operating` is of no use.
Be sure to insert this component in a `<tbody>` or it won't work at all.
What for errors in the console.